# How to put <label> & <select> in the same line?

Tags: wordpress

I'm having this trouble of getting my form label to be the same line with the .

Im using Visual Form Builder plugin for my form and there's a setting to set it to left-aligned. I've tested on the normal page on my Wordpress and it displays correctly. But when I use my theme's Tabs, Accordion, or Toggle, it doesn't appear correctly.

Here's my URL: http://www.mangerproduction.com/start-your-project/ Please click on "Get Quote" to see the form.

Thanks!

P/S: I know that this is mostly related to my theme's problem but I hope that I can solve it without the theme modification. I'm getting slow response from the theme support as well. Hope you can understand. :)

Comment: The select must be set to display: block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `.vfb-fieldset label{display: inline-block; *display:inline; zoom:1; }` to the end of your css file

Comment: Thanks Jason! How about making the <select> on the same vertical line?